# Flutter - Get the length of updated list using Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

Thanks for reading my questions first.

I would like to get the length of list using provider.

This is `main.dart` file.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Counts()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Times()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Check()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ListProvider>(
            create: (context) => ListProvider()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}
```

This is `Counts.dart` file that List Provider is in.

```
class ListProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<int> items = [
    0,
  ];

  void addItem(int item) {
    items.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool contains(int item) {
    bool answer = items.contains(item);
    return answer;
  }

  int length() {
    int len = items.length;
    return len;
  }
}

class DynamicList {
  List<int> _item = [];
  DynamicList(this._item);

  List get item => _item;
}
```

This is `shop.dart` file which I add items to the list.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cat_app/provider/counts.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'shopping.dart';

class shop extends StatefulWidget {
  const shop({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _shopState createState() => _shopState();
}

class _shopState extends State<shop> {
  bool inStock = true;
  var ownedItems;
  late DynamicList listClass;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ownedItems = Provider.of<ListProvider>(context, listen: false);
    listClass = DynamicList(ownedItems.items);
  }

  Widget buildShoppingCard(shopping Shopping) {
    return Column(children: [
      Card(
        elevation: 2.0,
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image(image: AssetImage(Shopping.imageUrl)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      OutlinedButton(
          onPressed:
              Shopping.inStock == true && context.watch<Counts>().count >= 3600
                  ? () {
                      context.read<Counts>().remove(3600);
                      Shopping.inStock = false;
                      ownedItems.addItem(Shopping.num);
                    }
                  : () {
                      Shopping.inStock = true;
                    },
          child:
              ownedItems.contains(Shopping.num) ? Text('Owned') : Text('Buy'))
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: shopping.samples.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return buildShoppingCard(shopping.samples[index]);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is a function of `mainhomepade.dart` file which I want to use the updated length of the list above.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var hat = 'assets/null.png';
  var acc = 'assets/null.png';
  var glasses = 'assets/null.png';

  void PlaySound(String soundName) {
    final _player = AudioCache();
    _player.play(soundName);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => ListProvider(),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => setting()));
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/gear.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => coin()));
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/coin.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/White_Ca.png',
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  glasses,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  acc,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  hat,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
                ),
                IconButton(
                    onPressed: (context.watch<Check>().check == 1)
                        ? () {
                            PlaySound('meow.m4a');
                          }
                        : null,
                    splashColor: Colors.white,
                    highlightColor: Colors.white,
                    icon: Image.asset('assets/null.png'),
                    iconSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.8),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => shop()));
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/bag.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: Swapping,
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/refresh.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Pomodoro()));
                  },
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/clock.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  Swaping() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int len = context.watch<ListProvider>().items.length;
    var numberHats = random.nextInt(len);
    var numberAccs = random.nextInt(acc_items.length);
    setState(() {
      hat = all_items[numberHats];
      //acc = acc_items[numberAccs];
    });
    print(len);
  }
}
```

I've tried `Swapping` function like this.
But `len` value is always one!
Even I checked it is updated on `shop.dart` file with button.

How can I get updated `len` value?
please help me !

Comment: Where do call the swapping function?

Comment: where do you use ` listClass` varriable?

Comment: @Josteve IconButton's onPressed called swapping function

Comment: @Saddan Shop.dart file!